# Value/Purpose of __attribute((const)) in gcc c++

Tags: gcc, optimization, attributes, g++

Is there any value in using `__attribute((const))` in gcc for c++ programs when declaring functions or static members that the compiler can see do not access global memory?

For example,

```
int Add( int x , int y ) __attribute((const))
{
    return x+y;
}
```

The compiler knows that this function is limited in its scope of memory access.  Does the attribute add anything?  If so, what?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`__attribute__((const))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in GNU C expresses the intent of the author of the function to not depend on any value other than its input arguments.

This allows the compiler to optimize multiple calls with identical arguments to such a function  into a single call without having to analyze the function body. This is especially useful if the function's body is in another translation unit.

In the case of `int Add( int x , int y ) __attribute__((const))`, multiple calls to, say `Add(2,3)`, could be coalesced into a single call and the return value could be cached, without knowing what `Add` actually does.

It also allows the compiler to verify that the function actually adheres to the declared intent.

Refer to [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/285332/) for more details and an example.

Comment: How does the compiler need this?   If you have a function that takes in items by value and doesn't reference any outside variables - shouldn't the compiler figure this out?